# Circuitikz misaligned cir

Tags: circuitikz

I am trying to sketch a high pass filter but the capacitive input is weird. Why is that?

```
\begin{circuitikz}
            \draw (0,0) node[op amp] (opamp) {}
            (opamp.-) to [R=$R_1$] ($(opamp.-)-(2,0)$) 
            to[C=$C_1$, *-o] (-4,0)
            (opamp.-) |- ($(opamp.-)+(0.2,1)$) to[R=$R_2$] ($(opamp.-)+(2.2,1)$) -|
            (opamp.out) to[short,*-] ($(opamp.out)+(.5,0)$) node [right] {$V_{out}$} node [ocirc] {} 
            (opamp.+) to[short]  ($(opamp.+)-(0,.5)$) node[ground] {}
            ;
        \end{circuitikz}
```

produces

[image]

Comment: Try ++(-4,0) for the cap destination

Comment: Welcome! Please can you make your code compilable rather than just giving a snipped? Which bit is the capacitive input and what's weird about it? Remember that people trying to help you will not necessarily or, even, generally be familiar with your discipline. 'The bit labelled R_1 is zig-zaggy and I need it to be rounded like a wave' is better than 'I expected a wiggly-woo, but the output shows a resistor'.

Comment: Or ++(-2,0), depending on what you're trying to do, but you need to provide an offset, and not an absolute position.  ++ is how you do that

Comment: Since (0,0) is the center of the op amp, (-4,0) will be even with it (vertically).

Answer (score 3):

with use of relative positioning:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\draw   (0,0)       node[op amp] (opamp) {}
        (opamp.-)   to [R=$R_1$] ++ (-2,0)
                    to [C=$C_1$, *-o] ++(-2,0)
        (opamp.-)   to [short,*-] ++ (0,1) coordinate (aux)
                    to [R=$R_2$] (aux-|opamp.out) 
                    -- (opamp.out)
        (opamp.out) to [short,*-o] ++ (.5,0)  node [right] {$V_{out}$}
        (opamp.+)   to [short]     ++ (0,-.5) node[ground] {};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]